# Normalizing difference between two real values to [0,1] interval

Tags: normalization, arithmetic

If I have two positive real numbers that can take on any value between 0 and some finite real number, how do I normalized the difference between these two numbers to [0,1] interval
where 0 indicates no similarity and 1 indicates that these two numbers are the same?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Several more duplicates can be found by linking through the [tag:normalization] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $L$ is the maximum value that any of the two numbers can take, than you can use the expression $sim(a, b) = 1 - \frac{|a-b|}{L}$.